# Parsing a dynamically built table a column is skipped and its value stored in the next column's place in the array

Tags: jquery, parsing

I have a dynamically built table (name = subTable) within a dynamically built table (id = programDetailTable). When I parse the table the 'Location' and 'Youth to Bring' columns are not being picked up and the value is stored in the next location in the array. Please see images:

[image]

[image]

Also, how do I pick up the value of the Activity Types in the sub table and associate them with the applicable row?

js:
Create table:

```
//Add an initial row if there are not currently any program lines
var newRows = "";
newRows += "<tr><td class='button'><button type='button' name='addPDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button></td>";
   newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='timeWidth pdValue' name='row0' value='07:00'></input></td>"; //Time
   //Activity table
   newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='activityWidth  pdValue' name='row0'></input>" //Activity
   newRows +=       "<table>";
   newRows +=           "<tbody id='activity2Tablebody'>";
   newRows +=               "<tr><td class='dropValue'>";
   newRows +=                   "<div class='droppableItem activityWidth'></div>";//Draged Activity Class
   newRows +=               "</td></tr>";
   newRows +=           "</tbody>";
   newRows +=       "</table>";
   newRows +="</td>";

   newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Location
   newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Equip. Needed
   newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Youth to Bring
   newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Leaders
   newRows += "<td class='button'><button type='button' name='removePDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></button></td></tr>";

$('#programDetailTablebody').append(newRows);
$( makeDroppable );
```

Parse:

```
function getProgramLines() {
    var records  = [];
    var keyNames = ['button1', 'plTime', 'plActivity', 'plLocation', 'plEquipNeeded', 'plYouthToBring', 'plLeaders', 'button2', 'activity2'];

    $("#programDetailTable tbody tr").each(function(i) {
        var record = {};
        $('td', this).each(function(j) {
            alert("j1:" + j + " keyNames[j]: " + keyNames[j]);
            if (keyNames[j]){
                alert("j2:" + j);
                    if ($.trim($(this).attr('class')) === 'keyvalue') {//Ignore the button columns
                        var text = $.trim($(this).find(".pdValue").val()); // GET TRIMMED TEXT
                        record[keyNames[j]] = text;
                    }
            }
        });
        records.push(record);
    });

    return records;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my complete solution to parsing the outer table and sub-table:

This is my solution (I have not implemented Bear's valuable suggestion yet):

Add the table and sub-table:

```
var newRows = "";
    newRows += "<tr><td class='button'><button type='button' name='addPDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button></td>";
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='timeWidth pdValue' name='row0' value='07:00'></input></td>"; //Time
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='activityWidth  pdValue' name='row0'></input>" //Activity
    //Activity table
    newRows +=      "<table name ='activityTable'>";
    newRows +=          "<tbody name='activity2Tablebody'>";
    newRows +=              "<tr>";
    newRows +=                  "<td class='dropValue'>";
                                    //Put a transparent div over the inputs elements so it can be dragged to remove
    newRows +=                      "<div class='dragabbleRemove'><div>&nbsp;</div>";
    newRows +=                          "<input type='text' class='droppableItem activityWidth' disabled></input>";//Droppable Activity Class
    newRows +=                      "</div>";
    newRows +=                  "</td>";
    newRows +=              "</tr>";
    newRows +=          "</tbody>";
    newRows +=      "</table>";
    newRows +="</td>";

    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Location
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Equip. Needed
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Youth to Bring
    newRows += "<td class='keyvalue'><input class='pdValue' name='row0'></input></td>";//Leaders
    newRows += "<td class='button'><button type='button' name='removePDRow'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></button></td></tr>";

$('#programDetailTablebody').append(newRows);
$( makeDroppable );
```

Handle the dropping of the item, make the field non droppable (only on drop on each row), make the div overlay of the dropped field draggable so it can be removed, add a new row to drop to:

```
function makeDroppable() {
    $('.droppableItem').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hovered',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var droppable = $(this);
            var draggable = ui.draggable;
            // Move draggable into droppable
            var drag = $('.droppableItem').has(ui.draggable).length ? draggable : draggable.clone().draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                stack: ".dragabbleItem",
                helper: 'clone'
            });
            //Add the dragged item to the row/field
            drag.appendTo(droppable);
            //Get the id of the draggable item
            draggableId = (draggable.prop('id'));
            //Stop the dropped item from being draggable
            drag.draggable('disable');
            //Set input value
            droppable.prop('value', draggable.text());
            //Set the name to the id of the element dragged onto it
            droppable.prop('name', draggableId);
            //Format the row/field dropped into with a blue background
            droppable.css({top: '5px', left: '5px', background: '#B0C4DE'});
            //Do not allow another item to be dropped into this row/field
            droppable.droppable('disable');
            //If this row/filed is dragged then remove it
            makeDraggableRemove();
            //Add a new row/field to drag to after the current table row
            //Put a transparent div over the inputs elements so it can be dragged to remove
            $("<tr><td class='dropValue' name='test2'><div class='dragabbleRemove'><div>&nbsp;</div><input type='text' class='droppableItem activityWidth' disabled></input></div></td></tr>").insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
        }
    });
}
```

Parse the tables:

```
function getProgramLines() {
    //Main table
    var records  = [];
    var keyNames = ['plRow','plTime', 'plActivity', 'plLocation', 'plEquipNeeded', 'plYouthToBring', 'plLeaders'];

    //Activity Classes
    var records2  = [];
    var keyNames2 = ['acRow','acId'];

        //Note: the > in the line below means only the main table is parsed and not the sub-table as well!
    $("#programDetailTable > tbody > tr").each(function(i) {
        var record = {};
        var k = 0;
        $('td', this).each(function(j) {
            if (keyNames[k]){

                if ($.trim($(this).attr('class')) === 'keyvalue') {

                    var text = $.trim($(this).find(".pdValue").val()); // GET TRIMMED TEXT
                    if (k === 0){
                        record[keyNames[k]] = i;
                        k++;
                    }
                    record[keyNames[k]] = text;
                    k++;

                    if (k === 6) {
                        records.push(record);
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("loop");
                    if ($.trim($(this).attr('class')) === 'dropValue') {

                        $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function(index,elem){
                            if (elem.name){
                                var record2 = {};
                                record2[keyNames2[0]] = i;//Store (link to) the main table row number
                                record2[keyNames2[1]] = elem.name;//Store the Activity Typde id
                                records2.push(record2);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    });

    return [records, records2];
}
```